Запуск приложения на хосте
Не запускается программа на хосте.
Залил свой сайт на хостинг, сайт должен запускать бота, написанного на Python, по нажатию кнопки. Сам сайт работает на Django и имеет установленное окружение и все необходимые библиотеки (хотя даже без них программа должна запускаться)
До нажатия кнопки всё работает, но запуска программы не происходит. Причем, это не ошибка программы (могло бы так быть, тем более, что господа держатели хостинга не дали мне никаких инструментов для отслеживания статуса чего-то другого кроме сайта). Ошибки нет, потому что даже вот такое (адрес там стоит верный, проверено приложениями сайта)
f = open('/var/www/111/data/2.txt', 'w')
f.write('хз')
f.close()

не запускается (2.txt не создается). Примечательно, что такая проблема у меня уже была, на том же хосте на другом тарифе, тогда мне в техпомощи сказали, что неверно установлен Django (!), что-то поколдовали (мне не сказали что), после чего я снова установил библиотеки, и всё заработало. Сейчас пока что техподдержка говорит, что им до лампы, и пытается слиться (не их, дескать, дело сторонние программы). Может было у кого?

Как установлен Джанго?

Согласно прилагаемой инструкции, через ispmanager и Shell-клиент. Правда, MySql библиотека не хотела ставиться, в самом сайте я сделал базой данных стандартную от Джанго (sqlite3)

прилагаемой? не вижу приложений к вопросу

"На сервере ****************** установлена операционная система Ubuntu 20.04 вместе с панелью управления ISP.
Мы не являемся разработчиками указанного ПО, и каких-либо изменений препятствующих запуску приложений с нашей стороны в него не вносилось." - ответ поддержки

Инструкция вот - https://www.ispmanager.ru/docs/ispmanager/ustanovka-django. Прилагаемая - это значит в моем сообщении, что сами серверодержатели мне ее предоставили
